# Unable to get Azure Service Principal access token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cors, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-principal

I'm trying to get access token of my service principal from the frontend(React) like below

```js
const response = await fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenent-id}/oauth2/token', {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: "follow",
      referrerPolicy: "origin",
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        "client_id": '',
        "grant_type": 'client_credentials',
        "client_secret": '',
        "resource": ''
      }),
    }).then(async (res) => { console.log('res:', await res.json()); })
```

but when I execute it I'm getting

```
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xx/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

So I've tried changing the mode to "no-cors" but I'm getting 400 error with empty response and not sure why this is happening as everything is same as before except for mode.I've also tried doing the same with CORS disabled in chrome & also in postman and it works.

Is there any way to make browsers ignore CORS for this request alone without getting 400 error. Or is there any other way to get token for the service principal? Appreciate the help!

**EDIT:** I'm using two different service principal, one for using MSAL (which works fine) and other for using our organization's internal API (one I'm having problem to get access token for).

Comment: You cannot use a service principal from a front-end app securely. The client secret is visible to anyone visiting the page. So Azure AD prevents it here.

Comment: A front-end application can only authenticate the user, it cannot authenticate itself as it runs in a non-trusted environment.

Comment: you can't make your app to fetch the `login.microsoftonline.com` request manually, and when you do this, a cors error is expect, we need to use msal in the application to  do the authentication and authorization. and juunas already explained the reason why msal is necessary.

Comment: If you want to enable CORS on the API, you can follow the instructions in the Azure API Management policy reference - cors article (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/cors-policy.md).